# Mostrar información en la misma vista del input

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo la siguiente vista en la que tengo un input y quiero mostrar información en esta vista del input, una vez se recoja. El problema es que como el modelo no ha recibido la información me da `NullReferenceException`. En mostrarla en otra vista no tengo ningún problema, pero sé que se puede hacer en la misma vista y quería saber alguna forma de hacerlo. Copio la vista y los métodos del controlador. Gracias

Vista

```
    <form action="/Ej4_1/Ej4_1_1" method="post">
    <label asp-for="Cadena"></label>
    <input asp-for="Cadena" name="Nombre" />
</form>  
     <ul>
        @foreach (var cad in Model.Rotaciones)
        {
            <li>@cad</li>
        }
      </ul>
```

Controladores

```
public IActionResult Ej4_1_1()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Ej4_1_1(Rotacion rot)
        {
            rot.RotarCadena();
            return View(rot);

        }
```

Comment: no puedes usar AJAX y cargarlo donde quieres? no entendí bien tu pregunta

Comment: Sí con AJAX se puede hacer pero sé que con .NET tiene que haber alguna forma y me gustaría saber cómo

Comment: crea un método en tu controlador que haga lo que quieras, llámalo por AJAX y que en la respuesta haga lo que necesitas, ¿no?

Comment: Me gustaría aprender a hacerlo con MVC.NET que es lo que estoy intentando aprender. No es tanto por resolver este problema concreto si no por saber cómo hacerlo. De todos modos muchas gracias por la idea ;)

Comment: si tu intención es que razor lo renderize, podrías emplear vistas parciales, trabajarlas como formas normales de .NET y cargarlas por AJAX donde las necesites en el formulario. [Ejemplo en inglés](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d551d3/how-to-load-partial-views-in-Asp-Net-mvc-using-jquery-ajax/)

Comment: Al estar trabajando con el patrón MVC, tienes que enviar el formulario al controlador para que éste se encargue de realizar la acción de guardar la info y retornar una respuesta hacia el cliente, por lo que la forma en que podrías hacer lo que deseas, es mediante JavaScript; distinto hubiera sido si utilizarás MVVM, el cual realiza un "pintado" de la información a medida que la vas escribiendo en un input por ejemplo

Comment: @L. Ronquillo le echo un ojo al enlace. Muchas gracias a los dos por las indicaciones. Pense que tenía que haber alguna forma de hacerlo únicamente con los controladores